# Need an easy way to delete HTML Code

Tags: html, bash

Here is the question.  I have a daunting task of deleting over 1400 entries of code manually.

This is what I have.  Everything before the  `<!-- Begin Description -->` has to be deleted and everything after the `<!-- End Description -->` also has to be deleted.  I need a script or something that can do this for me.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think this is a code request community, but more of a coding help community... So the next question is, what have you tried?

Comment: So do you have 1400 separate HTML files or 1400 sections in a single HTML file?

Comment: I have 1400 separate pages that need to be done and right now I am copying each one into notepad and deleting it by hand.  I would rather put into another program and use a script to remove it.

Comment: Craig.  I am not a coding wiz.  I know enough to be dangerous. Writing scripts is out of my realm.

Comment: @user3845947 : did you see my answer ?

Comment: Thanks guys we will try it out and see if we can get it to work

Comment: @user3845947 : Accept the answer if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 3):

With awk :

```
awk '/<!-- Begin Description -->/,/<!-- End Description -->/' file.html > new_file.html
```

example :

```
$ cat file
some code 
foo
<!-- Begin Description -->
some description
to keep
bar
<!-- End Description -->
some stuff
to remove
baz

$ awk '/<!-- Begin Description -->/,/<!-- End Description -->/' file
<!-- Begin Description -->
some description
to keep
bar
<!-- End Description -->
```

if you have 1400 files, you can make a loop in a shell :

```
for file in *.html; do
    awk '/<!-- Begin Description -->/,/<!-- End Description -->/' $file > ${file%.html}_new.html
done
```